# Files.ReadWrite ROPC MS Graph API 403 Error Though Scope shows correct authorization

Tags: sharepoint, file-upload, authorization, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

We have a use case in our corporation in which ROPC is deemed secure in which we upload a file to a sharepoint folder. The user has been granted the contributor role. When we log onto sharepoint as the user, she can upload a file.

However, when we try to do the same through our application, we are getting 403 forbidden. Looking at the token we get through ROPC, I see the following:

> Files.ReadWrite User.Read profile openid email

Why are we then getting 403 Forbidden when we try to upload the file?

A few more pieces of info:

1. Consent has been granted by the Administrator for the Delegated permission of `Files.ReadWrite`.
2. Application Manifest has `allowPublicClient` set to `true`.
3. In testing this use case, we were able to retrieve a user profile without problem, but for some reason the `Files.ReadWrite` says not authorized although the user can upload a file no problem from within Sharepoint.

Screenshot of API Permissions:
[image: Screenshot of API Permissions]

Decoded token part 1:
[image: Decoded token part 1]

Decoded token part 2:
[image: Decoded token part 2]

Failing Request:

```
    POST /v1.0/sites/92a99e5f-bb3e-4588-9461-d640b59d52e2/drives/b!X56pkj67iEWUYdZAtZ1S4hDhiQyamFVEj8y19ROdYOKYReOmD1sXSoDAvyFjD733/root:/Miriams%20Folder/FMW%20Management%20EM12c.pptx:/microsoft.graph.createUploadSession HTTP/1.1
    SdkVersion: graph-java/v2.4.1
    Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6InJNckJTQlBjNnlWZmVGVVZpbXhkYXEwdUpPMDNPQTFIWnZQQ01mV21uLUEiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCIsImtpZCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2dyYXBoLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20iLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3N0cy53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC83Y2I5M2QyOS0yZGRkLTQ5NDAtYTVjMC05NWM1MzY3NjJkOTAvIiwiaWF0IjoxNjA3MzU2NDk1LCJuYmYiOjE2MDczNTY0OTUsImV4cCI6MTYwNzM2MDM5NSwiYWNjdCI6MCwiYWNyIjoiMSIsImFjcnMiOlsidXJuOnVzZXI6cmVnaXN0ZXJzZWN1cml0eWluZm8iLCJ1cm46bWljcm9zb2Z0OnJlcTEiLCJ1cm46bWljcm9zb2Z0OnJlcTIiLCJ1cm46bWljcm9zb2Z0OnJlcTMiLCJjMSIsImMyIiwiYzMiLCJjNCIsImM1IiwiYzYiLCJjNyIsImM4IiwiYzkiLCJjMTAiLCJjMTEiLCJjMTIiLCJjMTMiLCJjMTQiLCJjMTUiLCJjMTYiLCJjMTciLCJjMTgiLCJjMTkiLCJjMjAiLCJjMjEiLCJjMjIiLCJjMjMiLCJjMjQiLCJjMjUiXSwiYWlvIjoiQVNRQTIvOFJBQUFBdUUvM3BaZjlXbE8ySWlaVkJlbzBURDFXK2VWR3o1RHN1YWNYRHF5VTU3WT0iLCJhbXIiOlsicHdkIl0sImFwcF9kaXNwbGF5bmFtZSI6ImFjY2VzcyBsZWVzIGZvbGRlciIsImFwcGlkIjoiOTkzNjQzNzktNDVhMC00ZGZhLTlkOTQtZDlhNDEwNTJjZDFjIiwiYXBwaWRhY3IiOiIwIiwiZmFtaWx5X25hbWUiOiJHcmFoYW0iLCJnaXZlbl9uYW1lIjoiTWlyaWFtIiwiaWR0eXAiOiJ1c2VyIiwiaXBhZGRyIjoiMjE2Ljk5LjE4MC4xNjMiLCJuYW1lIjoiTWlyaWFtIEdyYWhhbSIsIm9pZCI6IjZjODJiY2E3LTE5NjAtNGM1MS1iNjFjLWE3NDg3MTYyM2Y5ZiIsInBsYXRmIjoiMTQiLCJwdWlkIjoiMTAwMzIwMDBGMTZFRkNCRSIsInJoIjoiMC5BQUFBS1QyNWZOMHRRRW1sd0pYRk5uWXRrSGxETnBtZ1JmcE5uWlRacEJCU3pSeDFBTzAuIiwic2NwIjoiRmlsZXMuUmVhZFdyaXRlIG9wZW5pZCBwcm9maWxlIFJvbGVNYW5hZ2VtZW50LlJlYWQuQWxsIFJvbGVNYW5hZ2VtZW50LlJlYWQuRGlyZWN0b3J5IFVzZXIuUmVhZCBlbWFpbCIsInN1YiI6Im1MdTA4WFczc0RmNlF1c0lxZmVtRjViUUdySDlGYkRzQ0JLZ2w1RnljcXMiLCJ0ZW5hbnRfcmVnaW9uX3Njb3BlIjoiTkEiLCJ0aWQiOiI3Y2I5M2QyOS0yZGRkLTQ5NDAtYTVjMC05NWM1MzY3NjJkOTAiLCJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Ik1pcmlhbUdAdDg3N3NyZi5vbm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20iLCJ1cG4iOiJNaXJpYW1HQHQ4NzdzcmYub25taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tIiwidXRpIjoiR3U5V2FfalRORXFHSUJrdS0xaTlBQSIsInZlciI6IjEuMCIsIndpZHMiOlsiYjc5ZmJmNGQtM2VmOS00Njg5LTgxNDMtNzZiMTk0ZTg1NTA5Il0sInhtc19zdCI6eyJzdWIiOiJDQTFnQkttVU9nLVplc3otMEFmOWF1VVFHOHY0a283MlNoVGp1eEFlSjFNIn0sInhtc190Y2R0IjoxNjAzNzI3NjA4fQ.x5xY4qWUKQdYNOwlj0GWP0f8ICT10ojCQ1CKUoffDYm2W5FGKUMOZPx11dhZv6W2ye1Tm0v3Yd6lMm9nWOkXf5LhILLmLptX1SCA7K0fQ-ttgZRhFrtPf3_sEycaTDMTSIS4WtoDlQ1Z3kjv17F0N56cxWnmZli9YFPJCD54YZZingBzfZI4pd96XvuE9aVaZiB1P92kg7veMIjYczgvDgMijtTSnVgzzF06Uip0eRG5oQhnmz1VwLG2djJFPeu6Xm2zvsIF4-FTxDzEmjq-JQVo2GupAUVxVtUyZyrEsGupu763gpEfOvkgusKPnByZdPXGA1cPksosAA0fe4kbnA
    Accept: */*
    SdkVersion: graph-java-core/v1.0.5 (featureUsage=0) java/1.8.0_131
    client-request-id: edea4a1e-b722-4980-a688-ce1699af69bd
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 11
    Host: graph.microsoft.com
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    User-Agent: okhttp/4.10.0-RC1
```

Failing Response (ROPC):

```
    HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: application/json
    request-id: f00286fd-5ae6-488e-afd6-475ae7846906
    client-request-id: edea4a1e-b722-4980-a688-ce1699af69bd
    x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_71"}}
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
    Date: Mon, 07 Dec 2020 15:59:59 GMT
    Content-Length: 279
```

Successful Request (client_credentials)

```
POST /v1.0/sites/92a99e5f-bb3e-4588-9461-d640b59d52e2/drives/b!X56pkj67iEWUYdZAtZ1S4hDhiQyamFVEj8y19ROdYOKYReOmD1sXSoDAvyFjD733/root:/Miriams%20Folder/FMW%20Management%20EM12c.pptx:/microsoft.graph.createUploadSession HTTP/1.1
SdkVersion: graph-java/v2.4.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6Imp0M3ZlaW5pVkZPZTc1R0I5RG40Uk0ydEJlWTRkUEZOYTFiaDQwR1RFMmMiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCIsImtpZCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCJ9.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.AIj32kpkwVZiU6OM038yb4m7KQkQZ65PYSYGgS0M_ONhymtxhq7c1XAY-oTTw6jSyApb7d8lI37er-Qi9f47KXvhfEZlrpG0lX4ZOBcuqbPQagOTETT6Tn6FI5LKtIRm7SP2rICNUNzLuXip5D3_3i4Oil0AENQfu4eLjXr6YA5yIfjp4JUx_Ylh8eV9B0QM-na2BZLdrI3RfM0SY2ifFArxcWKQoaNUDinHYE952Wb5-SdgiX16Bi5-dN6LJiIhu4kScn3pHVbbpunBbk7aDTaPaqFeO7uuLycPIIkbu7vStTVX0mmRUXeg2wL6bU9tWo5YT5X93hi7oMYpoyQkNg
Accept: */*
SdkVersion: graph-java-core/v1.0.5 (featureUsage=0) java/1.8.0_131
client-request-id: 147bd003-d380-49ec-aa5a-6f18adef0021
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 11
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/4.10.0-RC1
```

Successful Response (client_credentials)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
Location: https://graph.microsoft.com
Vary: Accept-Encoding
request-id: bc409fcf-f957-4477-8e02-05d06f4724f1
client-request-id: 147bd003-d380-49ec-aa5a-6f18adef0021
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_12"}}
OData-Version: 4.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Mon, 07 Dec 2020 20:19:04 GMT
Content-Length: 1473
```

FOR SUCCESSFUL RUN, this is followed by

```
CONNECT t877srf.sharepoint.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: t877srf.sharepoint.com:443
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: okhttp/4.10.0-RC1
```

Plus all the chunking

Comment: Just added Files.ReadWrite.All and it still fails with the same error. This is what I get back from the request and it doesn't give me enough info to know what's going on: {
    "error": {
        "code": "accessDenied",
        "message": "Access denied",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-12-01T17:32:37",
            "request-id": "8a45fc34-a3c7-4bd1-bd7b-6908d8b201bc",
            "client-request-id": "8a45fc34-a3c7-4bd1-bd7b-6908d8b201bc"
        }
    }
}

Comment: We ran the same program using client_credentials and it works as long as permissions are Files.ReadWrite.All. We will not be able to use those permissions in production so we are trying to use Files.ReadWrite and ROPC.

Comment: Which api are you calling?

Comment: Through Postman, the MS Graph API call is PUT /sites/<siteid>/drive/root:/<subfolder>/<filename>:/content. In java, the same MS Graph API call is             graphClient.sites("<siteid>")
                .drive()
                .root()
                .itemWithPath(completePathOfFile)
                .createUploadSession(new DriveItemUploadableProperties())
                .buildRequest()
                .post();

Comment: This permission does not require the administrator's consent. Have you tried to use Graph explorer to call this API? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: I haven’t been able to test with Graph Explorer because: 1) Can’t add a binary file to body.. no way to do that. 2) Don’t know how to do Mime Multipart.

Comment: I need you to provide two screenshots: 1. Go to AAD>App registrations>your app>API permissions screenshots. 2. Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and take a screenshot.

Comment: screenshots added to original post

Comment: One more point I should mention: This works fine with grant_type=client_credentials and Files.ReadWrite.All but we are not allowed to have that permission in production

Comment: From your screenshot,  that there is no problem with your permissions. Can you provide a complete https request? Or the document you are referencing.

Comment: Request / response added to original post for both the ROPC and client_credentials use cases. ROPC fails, client_credentials works

Comment: If this is bug in Graph, what are next steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue encountered was due to the simple fact that the folder we are uploading to is not the root folder. For root Folder, Files.ReadWrite is sufficient; for other folders the permission Files.ReadWrite.All is required.